# How to read Python Array in C++

Tags: python, c++

I'm trying to call a python function within my c++ code and get back the return value. I did not had any trouble to do this with a single integer return value (see PyFnc1), however I have no idea how to do this with an array as return value (see PyFnc2).

PyFile.py

```
def PyFnc1(x):
    return x

def PyFnc2(x):
    return [x,x,x]
```

CppFile.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <C:\Python\Python312\include\python.h>

int main()
{
    PyObject* name, * load_module, * func, * callfunc, * args;

    Py_Initialize();    
    name = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"PyFile");
    load_module = PyImport_Import(name);
    func = PyObject_GetAttrString(load_module, (char*)"PyFnc1");
    args = PyTuple_Pack(1, PyLong_FromLong(1));
    callfunc = PyObject_CallObject(func, args);
    long retVal = PyLong_AsLong(callfunc);
    Py_Finalize();

    std::cout << retVal;
}
```

I try to use ByteArray and String functions, but nothing really worked out.

Comment: Maybe you should use the API for [list objects](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/list.html)?

Comment: If your only goal here is to call a python function from C++ and retrieve a list (array), you'd have to modify your code a little bit, but modification itself is going to make it extra easier - In python code, rather than returning list, you'd return tuple; then you'd modify the C++ code to handle tuples. You'd do if statements to check if `PyTuple_Check(callFunc)` and `PyTuple_Size(callFunc)` is equal to 3, if yes  `PyObject* element1 = PyTuple_GetItem(callfunc, 0);` and then you'd do `long retVal1 = PyLong_AsLong(element1);` - don't forget `Py_Finalize()` is outside the if statement.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I got it working by changing to tuple and following your instruction!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the method you are using. When working with Python lists in the C API, you should use `PyList_GetItem` to access individual elements. Also, you have to handle each element according to its type.

Try the following code with `PyList_GetItem` (I added additional checking to ensure the returning object is list):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <C:\Python\Python312\include\python.h>

int main()
{
PyObject* name, * load_module, * func, * callfunc, * args;

Py_Initialize();
name = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"PyFile");
load_module = PyImport_Import(name);

// PyFnc2 takes one argument, similar to PyFnc1
func = PyObject_GetAttrString(load_module, (char*)"PyFnc2");
args = PyTuple_Pack(1, PyLong_FromLong(1));

callfunc = PyObject_CallObject(func, args);

if (PyList_Check(callfunc)) {
    Py_ssize_t size = PyList_Size(callfunc);

    for (Py_ssize_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        PyObject* item = PyList_GetItem(callfunc, i);
        if (PyLong_Check(item)) {
            long element = PyLong_AsLong(item);
            std::cout << element << " ";
        } else {
            std::cerr << "Index " << i << " is not an integer." << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}else {
    std::cerr << "Object is not a list." << std::endl;
}


Py_Finalize();

}
```